# Create a table prefix in php as happens with Wordpress primitive queries

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello to all the members of Stackoverflow, my intent is to create a software, you should always create 3 environments:

- Development side
- Test side
- Production side

Obviously with different tables, but this is obvious, I was wondering if it was possible to do in php, what happens in Wordpress config.php or better, when installing the CMS you are asked to specify a prefix for the tables which will then be automatically installed .

So given a connection to the database in php:

```
$databaseHost = 'xxx';
$databaseName = 'xxx';
$databaseUsername = 'xxx';
$databasePassword = 'xxx';
$connessione = mysqli_connect($databaseHost, $databaseUsername, $databasePassword, $databaseName);
```

and the formulation of a query:

```
$q = $connessione->prepare("SELECT * FROM table“);
$q->execute();
$r = $q->get_result();
```

you could accomplish what happens in Wordpress primitive queries:

```
$wpdb->query("DELETE FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta WHERE meta_value = '0'  ");
```

where `$wpdb`

global variable together with:

```
{$wpdb->prefix}
```

it compiles the query taking into account the expert value as a prefix in the config.php file, so as to be able to differentiate the 3 environments.

How can it be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest that you would have 3 databases rather than all the tables in 1 database.  This allows a more consistent environment to test.

Comment: @NigelRen Of course, having 3 db, my question is canceled, but compared to the question?